# matplotlib multiple Y-axis pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Could someone give me a tip on how to do multiple Y axis plots?

This is some made up data below, how could I put `Temperature` its own Y axis, `Pressure` on its own Y axis, and then have both `Value1` and `Value2` on the ***same*** Y axis. I am trying to go for the same look and feel [of this SO post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640243/pandas-plot-multiple-y-axes). Thanks for any tips, I don't understand `ax3 = ax.twinx()` process, like as far as do I need to define an `ax.twinx()` for each separate Y axis plot I need?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



rows,cols = 8760,4
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols) 
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=rows, freq='H') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Temperature','Value1','Pressure','Value2'], index=tidx)


# using subplots() function
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25,8))
plt.title('Multy Y Plot')
 
ax2 = ax.twinx()    
ax3 = ax.twinx()    
ax4 = ax.twinx()

plot1, = ax.plot(df.index, df.Temperature)
plot2, = ax2.plot(df.index, df.Value1, color = 'r')
plot3, = ax3.plot(df.index, df.Pressure, color = 'g')
plot4, = ax4.plot(df.index, df.Value2, color = 'b')

ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Temperature')
ax2.set_ylabel('Value1')
ax3.set_ylabel('Pressure')
ax4.set_ylabel('Value2')


plt.legend([plot1,plot2,plot3,plot4],list(df.columns))

# defining display layout
plt.tight_layout()

# show plot
plt.show()
```

This will output everything jumbled up on the same side without separate Y axis for Pressure, Value1, and Value2.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding 4 different plots in one, which is not helpful. I would recommend breaking it into 2 plots w/ shared x-axis "Date":

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rows,cols = 8760,4
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols) 
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=rows, freq='H') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Temperature','Value1','Pressure','Value2'], index=tidx)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(25,8))
plt.title('Multy Y Plot')
 
ax1b = ax1.twinx()    
plot1a, = ax1.plot(df.index, df.Temperature)
plot1b, = ax1b.plot(df.index, df.Pressure, color='r')

ax1.set_ylabel('Temperature')
ax1b.set_ylabel('Pressure')

ax2b = ax2.twinx() 
plot2a, = ax2.plot(df.index, df.Value1, color='k')
plot2b, = ax2b.plot(df.index, df.Value2, color='g')

ax2.set_xlabel('Date')
ax2.set_ylabel('Value1')
ax2b.set_ylabel('Value2')


plt.legend([plot1a, plot1b, plot2a, plot2b], df.columns)

# defining display layout
plt.tight_layout()

# show plot
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plots]

Here I have added in the first plot (on the top) Temperature and Pressure and on the second plot (on the bottom) Value 1 and Value 2. Normally, we add in the same plot things that make sense to compare on the same x-axis. Pressure and Temperature is a valid combination that is why I combined those two together. But you can do as you wish.

Comment: Any chance you could help me one step further? On the bottom plot of `value 1  value 2` is it possible to get those on the same Y axis? (not split) In my real world scenario these have the same units

Comment: Actually I think I figured it out. Ill post an answer for how to do this as well. Let me know if that there is a better approach! And thanks again for the help!!!

Comment: What does `plt.tight_layout()` do?

Comment: @HenryHub Adjust the padding between and around subplots.

Answer (score 0):

This answer below uses [mpatches](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/users/legend_guide.html) is how to make the subplot of `Value1` and `Value2` on the same axis. The solution for this post has subplot for `Value1` and `Value2` on different axis. Thanks for the help @tzinie!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches


rows,cols = 8760,4
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols) 
tidx = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=rows, freq='H') 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Temperature','Value1','Pressure','Value2'], index=tidx)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(25,8))
plt.title('Multy Y Plot')
 
ax1b = ax1.twinx()    
plot1a, = ax1.plot(df.index, df.Temperature, color='r') # red
plot1b, = ax1b.plot(df.index, df.Pressure, color='b') # blue

ax1.set_ylabel('Temperature')
ax1b.set_ylabel('Pressure')


ax2.plot(df.index, df.Value1, color='k') # black
ax2.plot(df.index, df.Value2, color='g') # green
ax2.set_xlabel('Date')
ax2.set_ylabel('Value1 & Value2')


red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Temperature')
blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='Pressure')
green_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='Value2')
black_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='black', label='Value1')
plt.legend(handles=[red_patch,blue_patch,green_patch,black_patch])

# defining display layout
#plt.tight_layout()

# show plot
plt.show()
```

[image]